# How can I have list of figure etc. labelled D. List of Figures, E. List of Tables, F. Bibliography...?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, koma-script

I am using KOMA class scrreport and want the following structure of my appendix:

> A. Abbreviations
>   B. ...
>   C. ...
>   D. List of Figures
>   E. List of Tables
>   F. Bibliography
>   G. Acknowledgments

Right now, what I can achieve is

> A. Abbreviations
>   B. ...
>   C. ...
>   List of Figures
>   List of Tables
>   Bibliography
>   Acknowledgments

The relevant code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,colorlinks=true,pdftex]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

Using the KOMA class option `listof=totocnumbered` didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: It's always the best to add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the packages `tocloft` and `tocbibind` which aren't working great with a KOMA class. Normally these packages are not necessary. Most requests can be done by KOMA commands.

Simple remove these packages and everything works fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,colorlinks=true,listof=totocnumbered,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{Abbreviations  }
\chapter{...            }
\chapter{...            }
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\end{document}
```

KOMA provides also the functionality to add the bibliography to the table of contents. Therefore you can use the option: `bibliography=totocnumbered`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It turned out that the tocbibind package caused all problems. I am able to keep the tocloft package which I use to change the font of the toc, e.g. {\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\sffamily}}

Comment: I have to correct myself... also the tocloft packages has to be removed to achieve the correct sectioning - this leaves the question of how to change the font used in the toc...

Comment: @Leo26: Therefor you can use `\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\itshape}`

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I am using scrreprt with \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} and sectionentry is available only with scrartcl

Comment: @Leo26: This is only with a small hack possible. Or you are using `tocstyle`.

Comment: Thank you again! I had a look at tocstyle but am not experienced enough to see how to change the font of sections and subsections to sf :( So if you could possibly provide the hack to achieve these goals I would be most grateful...

Comment: @Leo26: `\bgroup\sffamily\tableofcontents\egroup` should work.

Comment: Beautiful - almost ;-) All I would need to be happy is that also the page numbers in the toc are displayed in sf. And what one should add is that this code has to be put after a \hyperset{...}, otherwise the latter will be ignored. Thanks!!

Comment: OK, to be precise, `\bgroup\sffamily\tableofcontents\egroup` has to be put instead of the `\tableofcontents`...

Comment: @Leo26: that's correct.

Comment: Do you also have a small hack for the page numbers? ;-)

Comment: @Leo26: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Right now, using your code, in the ToC section numbers and section titles are shown in sans serif, chapter page numbers too (the standard of the KOMA script), but section page numbers and subsection page numbers still show up in standard roman; in the ToC I'd like to have these page numbers in sf, too. Thanks!

Comment: @Leo26: Try: `\bgroup\let\familydefault\sfdefault\sffamily\tableofcontents\egroup`